# Do I need to dispose an GainNode after disconnect it?

Tags: web-audio-api

I am creating dynamically this chain.

```
osc1 -> gain1A -> gain1A -> ...
```

after I am done with it a create the same chain (with other parameters)

```
osc2 -> gain2A -> gain2A -> ...
```

I call `disconnect` in each of those nodes and `stop` on the `osc`. Using Firefox WebAudio window I see that the osc are disposed but the `GainNodes` stay there:

[image]

I am not sure if that is just a *"bug"* in Firefox or I need to do something else to that gain nodes so they are correctly disposed.

Comment: They will eventually disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you drop the references to the oscillator and gain nodes, then you shouldn't have to do anything.  As long as you stop the oscillator, you shouldn't have to disconnect them either.  They should all get collected.

But note that it may take a while for these to get collected.

It could be a bug in Firefox's visualizer; maybe it doesn't know about nodes that are collected.

Comment: can you add a reference to some official documentation or specification which backs your answer?

Comment: For example, see https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#dynamic-lifetime-example for how the browser is supposed to deal with nodes that are needed anymore.  Firefox's visualizer behavior is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Raymond. It should be noted that the section is explicitly "non-normative" though.

Comment: Yeah, the normative parts are a lot harder to read and understand.